# Can I limit a dependency in docker-compose.yml only for profiles local?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dependencies, local

For local development I am connecting to an SQL server running in a docker container in a VM.  However, for dev I am connecting to an Azure Server. The problem is that in my docker-compose.yml, for local development I have some services that depend on the sql-server and when I want to deploy to dev, I need to remove the sql-server service from my docker compose and then I need to remove the dependency that I have related to it, since I don't need it anymore as I am connecting to Azure. Is there any way to limit depedency (depends_on) only for profiles local?

This is what I would like to have but for me sounds like some sort of if conditional:

```
  sql-server:
    image: x
    environment: x
    pw: x
    ports: x
    healthcheck: x
    profiles: -local
  dependant-service:
    depends_on: sql-server ONLY when profiles: - local else it doesn't depend
```

Solution that I have currently is just to duplicate and have something for local and something for htttps. However this doesn't look very nice and it is not very efficient.

Comment: Are you saying that you know about Compose override files mechanism but you don't want to use it because it "doesn't look very nice" ?

Comment: I don't know what is that. what I am saying is that what i could do is something like: dependent-service: profiles:https, dependent-service-dublicate-for-local: depends_on: sql-server, profiles:local

Comment: the reason why i am saying that would not look nice is because I would have to duplicate almost 100 lines and that makes me think maybe I am doing something wrong :)

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with the `profiles` key but I think you might like to read about [extending](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/) and [overriding](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/).

Answer (score 1):

In Docker Compose, you can utilize the `profiles` attribute to define which services should be started under which profile. For your use case, you can define a `local` profile for your `sql-server` and any other service that should only run locally. Then, when you deploy to development, you don't activate the `local` profile, and those services won't be started or depended upon.

For local development:

```
docker-compose --profile local up
```

When you deploy to your dev environment where you do not need the `sql-server` service, you simply omit the `--profile local` option:

```
docker-compose up
```

This approach will allow you to have different configurations for different environments without duplicating a lot of content and allows for clean separation of concerns within your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: worked, i just overthought it. thanks a lot